# Как с помощью рефлекcии вытягивать свойство из обьекта по имени c#?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть класс

```
public class User 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Мне нужно сравнить строку (переменная типа string) с названием свойства обьекта. Например

```
if("Name" == (Название свойства обьекта))
```

Делал что типа

```
var a = myObject.GetType().GetProperty("inobjects")
```

Ничего не работает

Comment: `Ничего не работает` - в каком плане?

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ  Ничего не происходит

Comment: А что должно, по-вашему, произойти? Указанная вами строка должна найти нужное свойство без каких-либо проблем, а уже далее делайте с ним что вам надо, вы делаете? Как вы пришли к выводу, что "ничего не происходит"?

Comment: К тому же, у вас весьма странная логика, где вы сравниваете строку с названием свойства, которое по строке должны найти, не кажется тут странным что-то? Если вам надо убедиться в том, есть-ли свойство или нет, то делайте просто `.GetProperty("...")` и если вернет `null`, то объект не содержит такого свойства, без каких либо сравнений имен...